# Ubuntu 16.04 - no signal on startup

Tags: boot, nvidia

A few days ago I was working in Matlab when suddenly Matlab crashed. My screen then switched to a strange resolution of which I couldn't alter the settings. Therefore, I decided to reboot. Grub now also has a much smaller resolution than normal. After I press enter the screen turns off and shows a message that it isn't receiving a signal.

I've had problems with CUDA and Nvidia drivers before. After installing a driver I had a similar problem, except that the screen had a signal and had a white blinker in the top left corner. Another difference is that now I've had the Nvidia driver and CUDA working for a long time, and all of a sudden without installing or updating it, it has stopped working.

I've tried replacing `quiet splash` with `no splash`, after which I do get to see the Ubuntu logo, but afterward the no signal sign appears once again. I've also tried replacing `quiet splash` with `nomodeset`, same result except I now saw a purple screen before the no signal sign of my monitor.

Other solutions I've looked at tell me to open up a terminal, which I've tried but have failed to do so. I'm now a bit lost. What steps do I take next? The last time I reinstalled Ubuntu entirely. This time around I have a small part of my thesis on my computer, and I'd like to save it!

Comment: Try to remove both `quiet` and `splash` from grub this will display all kernel messages into the tty.

Comment: @Michal Same result unfortunately.